# Push Notification Using GCM with Asp.Net server

Tags: android

I have implemented push notification using GCM for my android app. Now i am getting the notification for all the registered device. But I am confused when should I unregistered my device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class DemoActivity extends Activity {

    TextView mDisplay;
    private String TAG = "** Demo Activity Push **";

    public final String SOAP_ACTION4 = "http://tempuri.org/InsertDeviceID";
    public final String OPERATION_NAME4 = "InsertDeviceID"; 
    public final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE4 = "http://tempuri.org/";
    public final String SOAP_ADDRESS4 = "http://www.icecup.com/iphonews/pushnotification.asmx"; 

    String regId ;
    String receivedString;
    String delreceivedString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(getApplicationContext()); 
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(getApplicationContext());
           setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);     
        regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            // Automatically registers application on startup.
            GCMRegistrar.register(getApplicationContext(), SENDER_ID);
        } else {
        Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");           
        }
       mDisplay.setText("ffffff        "+regId);
     //   setDeviceRegId(regId);
       // new MovieDetails().execute(regId);
       try {
            Class.forName("android.os.AsyncTask");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    public class MovieDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected  Void doInBackground(String... params) {          

            String parregid= params[0];
            Log.d("DEVICE REG ID", parregid);
            SoapObject request99 = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE4,OPERATION_NAME4);
            request99.addProperty("DeviceId",parregid);
            System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 1");
                SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope99 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                        SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                envelope99.dotNet = true;

                envelope99.setOutputSoapObject(request99);
                System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 2");
                HttpTransportSE httpTransport99 = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS4);
                System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 3");             
                SoapPrimitive  response=null;
                try {
                    httpTransport99.call(SOAP_ACTION4, envelope99);
                    System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 4");
                    response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope99.getResponse();    
                    System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 5");
                    System.out.println("RESPONSE IS:  "+response.toString());   
                    receivedString=response.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            super.onCancelled();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            System.out.println("I AM ALIVE 0");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute( Void result) {        

            System.out.println(" RESPONSE "+receivedString);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }


    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
            // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
            WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());            

            mDisplay.append(newMessage + "\n");         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            WakeLocker.release();
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        try {
            unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
             GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(getApplicationContext());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(
                    getString(R.string.error_config, name));
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main activity. Tell me where should I call GCM.Unregister(this) . Because if someone uninstall the app, for that registration id GCM server sends response **NotRegistered** to 3rd party server. So keeping that in mind I was thinking to unregister the device.

**GCMIntentService.java**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {


    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    String installregids = "";
    String uninstallregids = "";
    DemoActivity dact= new DemoActivity();

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);        

        this.installregids=registrationId;
         try {
        dact.new MovieDetails().execute(registrationId); 


           GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, true);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");

        this.uninstallregids=registrationId; 
         try {
             if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(context)) {
            //  dact.new MessgaeDelete().execute(registrationId);
                } else {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Ignoring unregister callback");
                }

           GCMRegistrar.setRegisteredOnServer(context, false);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
      //  String message = getString(R.string.gcm_message);
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        Log.d("Message Received", message);

        generateNotification(context, message);
    }


    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        // log message
        Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);

        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, DemoActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: You don't need to call it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally don't call `GCMRegistrar.unregister()`. You are automatically "unregistered" if you uninstall the application.
Purpose of this method is in my opinion solely to allow explicit deregistering from within the application. For example if the user has the possibility to turn auto sync completely off there is no need to be registered.
You can also not be notified about the fact that the app is being uninstalled. The app will never notice since there is no such thing like "preUninstall" or such.

Comment: Thank you deekay for your valueable comment. But then tell me how can we delete that id from the database in server side. Because I have tried uninstalling the app in one device out of 5 devices. But when .net server(3rd party server) is sending all 5 ids to the GCM server, in return GCM server is not sending NotRegistered response to .net server for that specific id. Rather it is sending valid message ID as response and I am receiving notification in remaining 4 devices.Because it is about 5 days that I have uninstall that app from 1 device,GCM server haven't send any NotRegistered response.

Comment: Sorry that sounds strange. It is stated that the GCM server will send NotRegistered when the application was uninstalled: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html (at bottom)
If I keep it in mind I will look into it for our application at work on monday.

Comment: I have solved that. But now I am facing one problem, i.e., if I am sending 2 notifications with an interval of 5 minutes bt them. In my device the last message is getting overriden to the older one. How can I make that in queue,i.e., both message will display.

Comment: You mean you want to show a `Notification`? Then use a unique value in the `NotificationManager.notify` method for the id parameter. Notifications with the same id will be replaced.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. I have solved that but facing a very strange issue from some days. After we have updated that app from play store(existing one was not having push notification), out of 5 devices I am not receiving notification in 2 devices (Galaxy Nexus and Samsung S3). What might be the problem???? Note: I have not deactivated my older apks from Play store account.